# How to get rid of seams when you make a new uv map?

Tags: uv-image-editor

I made a 2nd uv map for the eyes of my model but whenever I go into paint mode, the entire model's seams show up and in the way. How do I get rid of them so I can only see the eyes?

[image]

[image]